# D3 Axis Transition While Calling a Function

Tags: d3.js

My D3 chart has a Y axis which displays some ordinal values. When the data updates, changing the list of ordinal values, I want to transition to the new axis values. This would be fine except that the text displayed for each 'tick' of the axis needs wrapping to fit the web page the chart appears within. When I use a transition in calling the axis the text wrapping stops working.

My Y axis is initially created as follows:

```
this.yAxisTaskTypeGroup = this.chartGroup
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", "yAxisTaskTypeGroup")
        .attr("class", "y-axis-tasktype")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.yAxisTaskTypeVerticalOffset + ")");
```

My scale is defined as follows:

```
this.yScaleTaskType = d3
        .scaleOrdinal(this.yScaleTaskTypeRange)
        .domain(this.yScaleTaskTypeDomain);
```

My Y axis is defined as follows:

```
this.yAxisTaskType = d3.axisLeft(this.yScaleTaskType)
        .tickSize(0);
```

After the values for the Y axis scale's domain and range have been updated I update the axis as follows:

```
this.yAxisTaskTypeGroup
        .transition(this.timelineTransition) // apply a transition
        .call(this.yAxisTaskType)
        .selectAll(".tick text")
        .call(this.wrapText, this.margin.left, this.yAxisTaskTypeWrappedVerticalOffset);
```

The wrapText finction is as follows:

```
wrapText(text, width, wrappedTextOffset) {

    text.each(function () {
        let text = d3.select(this),
            words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
            word,
            line = [],
            lineNumber = 0,
            lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
            x = text.attr("x"),
            y = text.attr("y"),
            dy = 0, //parseFloat(text.attr('dy')),
            tspan = text.text(null)
                .append("tspan")
                .attr("x", x)
                .attr("y", y)
                .attr("dy", dy + "em");

        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            let node: SVGTSpanElement = <SVGTSpanElement>tspan.node();
            let hasGreaterWidth = node.getComputedTextLength() > width;
            if (hasGreaterWidth) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append("tspan")
                    .attr("x", x)
                    .attr("y", y)
                    .attr("dy", lineHeight + dy + "em")
                    .text(word);

                text.attr("y", wrappedTextOffset);
            };
        };

    });
};
```

If I remove the transition the text remains wrapped correctly and updates correctly. With the transition added, the text wrapping doesn't work, though the values update still. I want to calculate the text wrap and then transition the ticks to their new locations.

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong please?